# Laravel: Adding this service-provider to app.php gives "class log not found"

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to add this line to `app.php`:

```
         Stackkit\LaravelDatabaseEmails\LaravelDatabaseEmailsServiceProvider::class
```

... which of course *is* installed in my `vendor` directory.

But when I do so, commands like `artisan list` fail immediately with `"class 'log' does not exist.`

Is there *really* no way to force the actual PHP error-condition to be output?  I grow tired of shooting in the dark trying to resolve a problem, just because `class 'log'` is apparently eating the message and then choking on it.

Comment: 'log' is an alias to Laravel's Logger Facade, meaning something inside that LaravelDatabaseEmailsServiceProvider is attempting to log something before the alias has actually been defined. It might have to do with the order in which your providers are listed. I would search for `'log'` within that package's folder, and use a `dd(debug_backtrace())` just prior to every line where it's called upon.

Comment: The string `log` does not occur in the source code of LaravelDatabaseEmailsServiceProvider.

Comment: Not directly then. That'll make this a little harder. So, through previous trials, I happen to know that `Illuminate\Container\Container::resolve()` is what's responsible for looking up abstraction names in a library of concrete classes established by the Providers and app.php configs when the App is bootstrapped. So if you wrap the entire contents of that method in a try/catch, you should be able to get it to spit out the _entire_ error, complete with a stack-trace leading back to that package at the point of error. Alternatively, you could similarly tinker with `App\Exception\Handler`.

Comment: Is Laravel version used 5.4 and/or less?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in config/app.php to register the Facade if not registered

```
'aliases' => [
   //-----
   'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
]
```